# SQL Log file repeating error :error code 0x6fd

Tags: 2010, sql-server

**SQL Server 2008 R2**
Currently the log folder is taking upto 109GB's of space!

It keeps repeating the following error:

> “An exception occurred while enqueueing a message in the target queue.
>   Error: 15404, State: 11.Could not obtain information about Windows NT
>   group/user 'DOMAIN_NAME\sharepoint.admin', error code 0x6fd”

I have deleted the old logs, the new log file has reached 2.92Gb and is growing by the second.

How do I find out which DB is showing this error and how do I stop this error from occurring?
Thanks!

**UPDATE**
The log is growing around 7000 records per minute. Tried to check the server permissions given to DOMAIN_NAME\sharepoint.admin under "Effective" tab I am seeing the same error:

> "Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user
>   'DOMAIN_NAME\sharepoint.admin', error code 0x6e"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an access denied issue. Either your disconnected from the network or AD DS, or the account your using has expired credentials. Try to find the failing job in job history, and change that account to **sa** account. Then switch back to your service account - and see if you have the correct credentials. If not - look at the AD DS and make sure your credentils are valid.

Ref: [Replication Jobs fail with error code 0x6fd](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/repltalk/archive/2010/03/23/replication-jobs-fail-with-error-code-0x6fd.aspx)

Comment: That's the thing. I have only ONE job at the moment and it is running without errors. I am having trouble finding the source of this error.

Comment: The credentials for the account are current, the account is not locked and the credentials are picked properly at windows level in "users and groups" (local admin group)

Comment: The jobs running on the server were not an issue. I changed the owner of the various DB schema's used by Sharepoint from 'DOMAIN_NAME\sharepoint.admin' to 'sa' and the logs growth seems to have stopped.